# GHC version check in code

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm contributing to [Alex](http://github.com/simonmar/alex), and it obviously depends on a lot of libraries and should compile for a lot of versions.

I need to use a function that is only available from *GHC 7.6.1* to handle an error better. So I want to use an `#if ...` to import said function, else, I'll deal with the error differently.

I've seen some:

```
#if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 610
import Control.Exception ( bracketOnError )
#endif
```

So I did:

```
#if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 761
import Text.Read ( readMaybe )
#endif
```

Thinking that `761` is an alias to GHC version `7.6.1`, when I build the cabal package and try it out, the function doesn't get imported, even though I use *The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, **version 7.8.4***.

So after using a program to try it out, I find out that `7.8.1` identifies in `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__` as `708`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
module Main where

#if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ == 708
ver = "==708"
#else
ver = "/=708"
#endif

main = putStrLn $ ver
```

And running it:

```
$ runhaskell if.hs
==708
```

How can I know what value should I use for `7.6.1`, or is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's described in [section 6.11.3.1](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#standard-cpp-macros) of GHC's users guide:

> For version `x.y.z` of GHC, the value of `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__` is the integer ⟨xyy⟩ (if ⟨y⟩ is a single digit, then a leading zero is added, so for example in version 6.2 of GHC, `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__==602`). More information in [GHC version numbering policy](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/intro.html#version-numbering).

So for `7.6.1`, you would check `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 706`. The reason for this are versions like `7.10.x`.

Comment: Should I check for version `706` or `707`. Since `7.6.0` didn't have the function.

Comment: @chamini2 That seems unlikely. Minor version changes (the third number) should only fix bugs and are not supposed to change functionality otherwise (cf https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8778#comment:24). What is this function?

Comment: Ok, I understand. `readMaybe` from `Text.Read`. [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-6-1.html), in bullet *1.5.3.2 base*. So `706` should be ok?

Comment: @chamini2 If you want to depend on a version of base, you should do that instead of depending on a version of GHC. Use cabal's MIN_VERSION family of macros (again read the fine documentation to learn more about how they work).

Answer (score 8):

As Daniel Wagner indicated, the most correct way to check for package version is usually to use a Cabal `MIN_VERSION` macro. For example, you could use

```
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,6,0)
```

to determine if the `base` package is at least version 4.6.0, which is the earliest version with the function you seek.

The `base` package is a little weird. It was used both by GHC and by the now-defunct Hugs and NHC implementations. Using the Cabal macro was then a more portable way to check the `base` version. These days, GHC is the only one using `base`, so the portability argument is a little less clear, but that approach also has the advantage of checking the major and minor version numbers.

Since `base` versions are very tightly tied to GHC versions, you can define a reasonable fall-back form of `MIN_VERSION_base` for compiling without Cabal, using `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__` to estimate the `base` version. The current `containers` head conditionally defines such a fall-back.

#### Update

As of GHC 8, the compiler itself has taken over the job of defining `MIN_VERSION` macros. This is great, because you now get to use these macros whether or not you build with Cabal. No more ugly approximations!

Answer (score 7):

Read the [fine documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#c-pre-processor):

> For version x.y.z of GHC, the value of `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__` is the integer xyy (if y is a single digit, then a leading zero is added, so for example in version 6.2 of GHC, `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__`==602). More information in Section 1.4, “GHC version numbering policy”.
>
> With any luck, `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__` will be undefined in all other implementations that support C-style pre-processing.
>
> (For reference: the comparable symbols for other systems are: `__HUGS__` for Hugs, `__NHC__` for nhc98, and `__HBC__` for hbc.)
>
> NB. This macro is set when pre-processing both Haskell source and C source, including the C source generated from a Haskell module (i.e. .hs, .lhs, .c and .hc files).