# How to inspect CPP pragmas in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, preprocessor

I have such code in program:

```
#if ( __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 821 )
  ...
#else
  ...
#endif
```

But it doesn't work as expected. Most likely because I used wrong CPP pragma. So I wonder is there some easy way to inspect value of defined constants or to evaluate CPP pragma?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll need to explicitly specify that you intend to use CPP for preprocessing via the `LANGUAGE` pragma.

For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
module Main where

#if ( __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 821 )
ver = ">= 821"
#else
ver = "< 821"
#endif

main = putStrLn $ ver -- < 821 on my machine
```

See:

- [GHC version check in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292476/ghc-version-check-in-code)
- https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html

Edit:

You should be able to use preprocessing wherever you need to (I *think* this example addresses the "values inside your project" requirement you refer to in your comment below):

```
-- Bar.hs
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
module Bar(ver) where

#if ( __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 821 )
ver = ">= 821"
#else
ver = "< 821"
#endif

-- Foo.hs
module Main where

import Bar

main = putStrLn $ ver -- < 821 on my machine
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your solution is good. My project compiles. I know that I should enable `-XCPP` pragma. I was interested in some simple solution. Perfectly — using `ghci`. I'm interested in values inside my prorject, not in isolation. Creating new `Main` file for such purposes is not really convenient...